# Android canvas.drawLine() cannot draw straight horizontal line

Tags: android, canvas, paint

So I'm trying to draw a horizontal line in Android Studio with canvas.drawLine()

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    bg.draw(canvas);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    canvas.drawLine(0, 600, 1000, 600, paint);

    player.draw(canvas);
    for ( Missile m : player.getMissiles()){
        m.draw(canvas);
    }


}
```

paint variable is initialized like so :

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
```

This is what it looks like in the Android emulator: http://puu.sh/jc7O7/95cdd84355.jpg

It's jagged in the middle for some reason. I've tried to setAntialias, dither, strokeWidth, length, and stroke type. Also, null instead of paint variable in the drawLine method. I've tried googling for any similar problems, but I haven't found anyone to have this problem. Looking at the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html for drawLine method, I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct parameters.

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

edit: I've done draw line in Java in Eclipse before, but for some reason I can't in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to draw a rectangle instead with height of 10 by drawRect()?

Comment: Here's how it looks: http://puu.sh/jc8nd/9ed0ac4ec4.jpg It's still there... This is the code I used  canvas.drawRect(0, 600, 1000, 630, paint);